# Error: ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

I have an OracleXE 11g instance on a remote server machine. Some developers who have Russian Windows 7 SP1 can't connect to it. They got this error message:

ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified

There is no error if you use enUS Windows 7 SP1 machine. I tried many ways to solve this:

I checked language settings on server machine:

```
SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS;
SELECT USERENV ('language') FROM DUAL;
```

Both returns GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8.

I tried different ways to solve this issue by doing this:

1. Rename registry key NLS_LANG to NLS_LANGX on server machine. Did nothing.
2. Create NLS_LANG environment variable with value of GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8.
3. Control panel > Regional and language options > Format and set Russian there.

None of this works. What should I do?

Comment: In SQL Developer the problem can be solved by adding these line to config: AddVMOption -Duser.language=en
AddVMOption -Duser.country=US But how to change it globally?

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

had similar problem
adding following to VM arguments helped:

```
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.region=us
```

Comment: Same issue using DBever,Mac users add the entries to /Users/hanh/Applications/DBeaver.app/Contents/Eclipse/dbeaver.ini
# OR
/Applications/DBeaver.app/Contents/Eclipse/dbeaver.ini

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem with MacOS, when installing SQL developer several times. Adding VM option helped me (@kilonet answer). But here I am adding a new answer specifically for resolve MacOS problem.

Modify SQL Developer product configuration file (product.conf) in below path.

```
~/.sqldeveloper/<sqldeveloper version>/product.conf
```

Add add following two entries.

```
AddVMOption -Duser.language=en
AddVMOption -Duser.region=us
```

Thanks for question and the answer.

Answer (score 2):

setting _JAVA_OPTIONS is an alternative global solution to all the Java applications are stating in a terminal.

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=us'
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQLDeveloper in Windows

```
sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf
```

Commment this line

```
AddVMOption -Duser.timezone="-06:00"
# AddVMOption -Duser.timezone="-06:00"
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just change the regional and language in your OS, make sure it matches with the oracle regional and language.

Open SQLDeveloper -> Preferences -> Database -> NLS

REF: https://rapidsol.blogspot.com/2018/10/ora-00604-error-occurred-at-recursive.html